# IE9 hangs local Flask instance

Tags: python, firefox, internet-explorer-9, flask

A web app I am working on works fine under Firefox and IE8 from virtual box. But when I try to load it with IE9, it tries to load the page but after a while stops loading. Then I try to load the same url with Firefox again and it doesn't load at all. Then I restart Flask and the same happens - I can work normally with the app through FF but not IE9.
Looks like a kind of a bug, doesn't it?

Here is the exception Python throws:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 6924)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 639, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Cosmo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 189, in handle
    return rv
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'rv' referenced before assignment
```

I have uploaded code to my hosting and it works fine there.

I think the issue from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461780/python-flask-problems-with-minitwit-on-internet-explorer-9) is similar to my one.

Comment: Could you please share your code? Otherwise, we have no way of reproducing the problem. Also, which version of python are you using?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a git version of werkzeug. [According to the author](http://groups.google.com/group/pocoo-libs/browse_thread/thread/9aa34499c6835927?pli=1), a similar bug was recently fixed.

Comment: @trinth try to use app.run(threaded=True) instead of app.run() that is single-threaded by default, it worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I've been having problems with IE hanging my flask server with more recent versions of Flask/Werkzeug (+2 years from this thread). The solution I found was to use `run(threaded=True)` as described in this other question: [Can I serve multiple clients using just Flask app.run() as standalone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814201/can-i-serve-multiple-clients-using-just-flask-app-run-as-standalone)

Comment: I fixed the typo. Did you really think that was a constructive comment? There's a reason that stackoverflow lets you suggest edits to other people's answers.

Comment: Agree. I would have welcomed a correction. Saying that there's no true in Python is snarky.

Comment: This answer should be on top. A long time has gone since the question was originally posted, and I bet that most if not all of the people reaching to it now are looking for this answer, not for the development version of werkzeug