# How do I upload a large file without blocking my webserver? Using python and Amazon Beanstalk/EC2

Tags: python, file-upload, amazon-ec2, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm currently creating an image upload system using Python and Flask running on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.

Everything works fine, but the problem is that the upload blocks the entire web server, including incoming page load requests.

How do I make the file upload run as a separate process? Or allow additional incoming requests? Will this happen automatically if I increase the number of processes available in EC2?

Comment: See this question for some approaches you can take here.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814201/can-i-serve-multiple-clients-using-just-flask-app-run-as-standalone

Comment: well that was easy...setting "threaded=true" in the main run function did it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm putting this as an answer.

You can set the threaded parameter in the main function in [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True)
```