# Flask gives "error 32 broken pipe" when being requested too often

Tags: python, flask, server

I write a very simple flask server. This server response to `GET` and give back my home.html.
I visit the site on 127.0.0.1:5000

everything is good till now.

However, if I keep pressing "fresh" (Command+R on my computer) a lot of times for a few second, as fast as I can, then, my flask give this error and breaks down.

> Exception in thread Thread-1:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in **bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
>       self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 659, in inner
>       srv.serve_forever()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 499, in serve_forever
>       HTTPServer.serve_forever(self)
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 238, in serve_forever
>       self._handle_request_noblock()
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 297, in _handle_request_noblock
>       self.handle_error(request, client_address)
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
>       self.process_request(request, client_address)
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
>       self.finish_request(request, client_address)
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
>       self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init**
>       self.handle()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 216, in handle
>       rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
>       self.handle_one_request()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 251, in handle_one_request
>       return self.run_wsgi()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in run_wsgi
>       execute(self.server.app)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 184, in execute
>       write(data)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 152, in write
>       self.send_header(key, value)
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 401, in send_header
>       self.wfile.write("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value))
>   IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

I believe this is what happened: When my server was trying to transmit html to my browser, I pressed the refresh and broke the pipe. So my server got confused and then give error.

How to solve this problem? Or this site is not usable as all since anyone who ask constantly for my page can break my webpage down.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can try using `app.run(threaded=True)` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14823968/4668640) SO answer.

Answer (score 1):

This error appear because your server is overloaded! Stop and start it!

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error too in an Ubuntu Docker container on Kubernetes on Ubuntu VM:

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 261, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 227, in write
    self.send_header(key, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 412, in send_header
    self.wfile.write("%s: %s\r\n" % (keyword, value))
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I created a brand new Ubuntu xenial VM and ran the same code in Ubuntu Docker container on Kubernetes, and this error was **not** seen and Python Flask worked as expected. I think it was issue with my host (Ubuntu VM).

Answer (score 1):

built-in werkzeug is not capable of handle concurrent requests the connection while the server is still churning its content out.

rather than using

```
 app.run(debug=True,port=5000)
```

you should try this

```
from gevent.wsgi import WSGIServer
http_server = WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
http_server.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Flask are you using, version 0.12/0.13, or an older one?

You’re seeing this error because your server doesn’t handle concurrent requests. You need a proper WSGI server that is capable of handling concurrent requests ( use  gunicorn or uWSGI in multithreaded environment) and it should work fine.
Check: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWeb

What happens is that you are making a second request through reload to your flask app while it is still busy processing the first request. It won't respond to this second request until it is done with that first request. The requests.post() function is waiting for Flask to respond, but Flask itself is waiting for post()

Also enable threads in the Flask-supplied server using:

```
app.run(threaded=True)
```

Also note that Python 3 the socketserver implementation handles the disconnect more gracefully and continues to serve rather than crash.