# Connecting to localhost Flask server from network computers

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask server running on one of my machines, with the app.run line looking like so:

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug = False, host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5000)
```

When I run the program it says,

```
    * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
```

and I can access it *perfectly fine from my own machine*, but whenever I try to connect *from another computer* using the URL `192.168.1.131:5000`, the connection is *stuck* loading and times out.

I'm not sure why this is happening, if you could identify the problem that would be great.

Comment: This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14823968/2800058)

Comment: @pjcunningham The post you mentioned does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Is the other computer is connected to your local network?

Comment: Setup Gunicorn to serve for the app.It will take you 10 minutes tops. Flask standard server is really just for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You must replace '0.0.0.0' with your local network IP.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = False, host = '192.168.1.131', port = 5000)
```