# How to solve Lazy loading and production enviroment in a dash application?

Tags: python, flask, server, plotly-dash

I did a dash app which works in a development enviroment in my own computer. I want to use the same files in other computer, and continue developing the code from there. I copied everything but it shows me a warning like this:

```
Serving Flask app "myDashApp" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
 WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
 Use a production WSGI server instead.
```

I saw that [some users had similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284753/warning-message-while-running-flask) but I don't manage to solve it. Anyone has any idea of how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I used the package waitress instead of pure python. So I run my app like this:

```
waitress-serve my_dash:app.server
```