# Server runs in terminal but doesn't appear in the page. Serving Flask app "application" (lazy loading)

Tags: python, flask, amazon-s3

- Serving Flask app "application" (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
  WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: off

  @application.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
  @application.route('/')
  def default():

Originally, running python application.py works - the page appears but after a while of doing the same thing, the web page doesn't appear anymore and instead the warning above shows in my terminal. What is the problem?

Comment: Any chance you could share the startup portion of the app code? And are you running Flask via the command line, or via an IDE debugger?

Answer (score 0):

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/deploying/

" While lightweight and easy to use, Flask’s built-in server is not suitable for production as it doesn’t scale well and by default serves only one request at a time. "

I also found this: [warning message while running flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284753/warning-message-while-running-flask)

If you search with the warning/error message you get, you will find questions that were already answered.